# Using sys.argv how to store keys and values to accumulate overtime?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very happy to have found this website and I know the rules said to make sure I look up my question before asking here. I did but maybe I missed something. I found a project to work on using Python 2.7 and perhaps I'm not connecting the dots well. I want to build a dictionary (small database I suppose) so I wrote a script with an empty dictionary and command line arguments to add keys and values to the dictionary. Unfortunately it doesn't store the keys and values it only outputs the dictionary with the command line arguments at the time. I'm wondering how can I store the command line arguments into the dictionary? More specifically, every time I add keys and values as command line arguments they will accumulate overtime.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to persist the data to the harddrive and restore already persited data from the harddrive on each start of the script. then you put in more parameters and store it again. Happy Coding. The Help you are getting her is in fixing Code - not implementing your ideas. Please go over the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and one more tip - use Python 3.6 instead of 2.7 which is outdated for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the module `shelve` for a persistent dictionary:

```
import shelve

db = shelve.open('cmd.db')
```

Update with your dictionary:

```
db.update(my_dict)
```

`db` behaves mostly like a dict.

> A "shelf" is a persistent, dictionary-like object.  The difference
>   with dbm databases is that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can
>   be essentially arbitrary Python objects -- anything that the "pickle"
>   module can handle.  This includes most class instances, recursive data
>   types, and objects containing lots of shared sub-objects.  The keys
>   are ordinary strings.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed. I implemented shelving and it worked out. Thank you!